# How can I define a transition making the content appear from outside the screen in MotionLayout?

Tags: android, animation, percentage, android-motionlayout

I am using MotionLayout and I want to make the content appear sliding from the bottom of the screen. I want to use translationY but I cannot define %. I have to define dp. Is there a way to achieve it writing it in a ?

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done by constraining top_toBottom and defining its height as a percent.
This would position it directly outside the bottom edge.